# How to get a slack notification when build fails?

Tags: drone.io

When my build is successful I get a slack notification, when it fails I do not. Looking at the Drone web UI it looks like it stops once the build fails and the [slack plugin](https://github.com/drone-plugins/drone-slack) is never run.

A successful build results in `notify` happening:

[image]

A failed build does not get to the notify stage:

[image: failed build]

The key parts of the `.drone.yml` are as follows:

```
  build:
    image: propheris/ruby:2.4.0
    secrets: [gems_password]
    commands:
      - exit 0     

  notify:
    image: plugins/slack
    webhook: https://example.com/hooks/token
    channel: dev
    username: drone
    icon_emoji: drone
```

I change `exit 0` or `exit 1` to simulate a successful or failed build.

- Drone 0.7
- plugin/slack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken a look at the docs and it seems your missing the following line:

```
when:
    status: [ success, failure ]
```

The [docs](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-slack/) state:

> Example configuration for success and failure messages:

```
pipeline:
  slack:
    image: plugins/slack
    webhook: https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
    channel: dev
    when:
      status: [ success, failure ]
```

You can also add custom messages:

> Example configuration with a custom message template:

```
pipeline:
  slack:
    image: plugins/slack
    webhook: https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
    channel: dev
    template: >
      {{#success build.status}}
        build {{build.number}} succeeded. Good job.
      {{else}}
        build {{build.number}} failed. Fix me please.
      {{/success}}
```

Comment: Scratch that, it seems, it has to be, as indicated in the docs `status: [ success, failure ]` not `status: [success, failure]` as I had.